# `react-video-recorder` stuck at loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to use [`react-video-recorder`](https://github.com/fbaiodias/react-video-recorder) in my app. I see the demos, both in Stackblitz and the Storybook in [Vercel](https://react-video-recorder.vercel.app/). Both works just fine in my browsers.

But when I implement it in my code, it just shows the component, asks for mic and cam permissions, and then it's stuck at "Loading...". My camera LED lights up for a few seconds, and turns back off.

I installed the package using the recommended method (`yarn add react-video-recorder react react-dom prop-types styled-components`). I have Node v16.14.2, React v18.1.0 and react-scripts v5.

I just wrote a very basic implementation of React Video Recorder. Like this:

```js
import VideoRecorder from "react-video-recorder"

export default function CreateMyIntro () {
  return (
    <VideoRecorder />
  )
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue. According to the issues tab on their GitHub, the module does not work with React 18. Try downgrading to React 17. See [their GitHub Issues](https://github.com/fbaiodias/react-video-recorder/issues/172)

*Edit: As of 10/14/22 version [3.19.4](https://github.com/fbaiodias/react-video-recorder) was released, which includes compatibility for React 18. Try updating to most recent version, I just tested it and it is working now with React 18.